# Removing multiples of a number from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm new to Python and i'm working on a program which finds the prime factors of a number. My code so far looks like this:

```py
num = int(input('\nEnter a natural number greater than 1: '))
if num <= 1:
    while num <= 1:
        num = int(input('\nI said greater than 1: '))
if num == 2:
    print('\n', num, 'is a prime number.')
else:
    toggle = 0
    flist = []
    for i in range(2, num - 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            flist.append(i)
            toggle = 1
    if toggle == 0:
        print('\n', num, 'is a prime number.')
    if toggle == 1:
        print('\n', num, 'is not a prime number.')
        print('\nIt\'s prime factors are:', flist)
```

With an input of 30 for example i get this output:

```
Enter a natural number greater than 1: 30

30 is not a prime number.

It's prime factors are: [2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15]
```

The prime factors in this case are `2`, `3`, `5`. How can i remove their multiples ?
Thank you.

Comment: `if num<=1: while num<=1:` - You can avoid the redundant `if` here.

Comment: By the way, `True` and `False` is more intuitive for toggle than `0` and `1`.

Comment: You could do a prime sieve, and then go through each prime, and check if your number is divisible by the prime

Answer (score 2):

I would define an extra function to check if a number is prime

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n>1:
        for i in range(2,n):
            if (n % i)==0:
                return False
    return True
```

Then I would use it inside you code to check if a number is prime before to add it to the final list of prime factors.

```
num = int(input('\nEnter a natural number greater than 1: '))
if num <= 1:
    while num <= 1:
        num = int(input('\nI said greater than 1: '))
if num == 2:
    print('\n', num, 'is a prime number.')
else:
    toggle = 0
    flist = []
    for i in range(2, num - 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            if is_prime(i):   # append only prime numbers
                flist.append(i)
            toggle = 1
    if toggle == 0:
        print('\n', num, 'is a prime number.')
    if toggle == 1:
        print('\n', num, 'is not a prime number.')
        print('\nIt\'s prime factors are:', flist)
```

This gives you the right output:

```
Enter a natural number greater than 1: 30

 30 is not a prime number.

It's prime factors are: [2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: This is dead on, a prime sieve really is the way to go for speed though

Comment: @Edoardo Guerriero I used your method and it worked fine. Thank you. One question though: I didn't replace n with num and it still works. How can this be? Variable n hasn't been defined.

Comment: @Kos in the function definition you can call a variable however you want, it doesn't matter, There would be a problem only if a variable is used inside the function without being defined or declared as an argument (n here is declared as an argument). When you use the function in your code, 'n' becomes i, which is defined because you use it as an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the Sieve of Eratosthenes to first find all primes beneath N and then go through those to find all prime factors, this should be pretty efficient

```
import numpy as np

def findSieve(num):
    allN = np.arange(1,num+1,1)
    mask = allN == allN
    maskN = np.ma.MaskedArray(allN)
    p = 2

    while maskN[p:].count() > 0:
        mask = mask & ((allN%p != 0) | (allN <= p))
        maskN = np.ma.MaskedArray(maskN, mask =~ mask)
        p = maskN[p:].min()

    return np.asarray(maskN[maskN.mask == False])

def findPrimeFactors(num):        
    sieve = findSieve(num)
    flist = []
    num_factored = num
    for i in range(1,len(sieve)) :
        while num_factored % sieve[i] == 0:
            flist.append(sieve[i])
            num_factored = num_factored // sieve[i]
            if num_factored == 1:
                break

    prime = len(flist) == 1
    if prime:
        print('\n', num, 'is a prime number.')
    else:
        print('\n', num, 'is not a prime number.')
        print('\nIt\'s prime factors are:', flist)


num = int(input('\nEnter a natural number greater than 1: '))
findPrimeFactors(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the multiples of your prime factors, such as 6 = 2 × 3, 10 = 2 × 5 and 15 = 3 × 5.

To avoid those, you should divide your initial number by the prime factors as you find them, so that it won't divide again by the multiples of those prime factors.

Also, you should do that repeatedly, since numbers often have an exponent of a prime factor (for instance, 12 = 2² × 3, so you should divide by 2 twice.)

```
for i in range(2, num):
    while num % i == 0:
        flist.append(i)
        num = num // i
    if num == 1:
        break
```

When you get to 1, you know you can stop.

There are also other optimizations you can do, for instance when i² is larger than num, you know num must be a prime, since you already divided it by all factors smaller than i.

You can also skip even numbers after 2, since those will never be factors.

Using the simple code above, you'll know that num is a prime whenever flist is empty. (You don't need an extra toggle to track that.) That works, since you're never dividing by num itself, so if you get to the end and haven't divided once, that means it's a prime.

For a number such as 12, your flist will have `[2, 2, 3]`. If you want the *unique* prime factors, without repetitions, you can use `set(flist)` to get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: This still won't find prime factors until the line in the while actually identifies only prime factors